# how to plot an array directly using plotutils

Tags: arrays, linux, plot

I'm trying to plot an array.. for example [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
I know that we can plot files, but I want to plot directly like:

```
    plot [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
```

is that possible and how??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go..

```
    echo 1 2 3 4 | graph -T ps -a > plot.ps
```

you will find it in the same directory
you can also add extra arguments to color the plot and optimize it...